# I need jquery regular expression to validate password with form validate plugin

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a password with a regex using the extended rule `patern` that comes with the form validation plugin. I've tried many expressions from the internet and so far none meets my requirement or for some reason they just don't work as described. What I need is to validate the following:

1. password must have from 6 chars to 20
2. it must contain at least one upper case
3. it must contain at least one number
4. it must contain at least one lower case
5. it must be possible to have repetitions
6. it must not matter the possition of the chars
7. it must not allow blank spaces
8. special chars from a subset of them should be optional

So, users should be able to input the below examples:

1. aaaaaa1A
2. Passw0rd
3. abCdef9
4. $$$h1Tzzzz

I thought of just seeing here if anybody can help me with this. I'm not a regex expert.

Answer (score 5):

[image: XKCD]

You should allow the user to enter whatever password they want.

Anyway, your task is probably better done as several tests, one-by-one. Not only is this easier to program, it also lets you tell the user exactly why you aren't accepting their password.

Comment: Thanks, Kolink. You are making a good point. Unfortunately, considering the type of audience the application is for, if I don't force users to at least enter an upper case, the majority of them will use `1234` as their password. I take your advice of doing partial validations so the error can be better communicated to users. However, I don't think the form validate plugin supports that. Do you know?

Comment: Why not just write your own code? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regexes for that.

You have a list of checks: just check using regular string functions.

Answer (score 0):

Although using regexp should be considered twice. Here is how you can do it:

```
var pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=[\$!]).{6,26}$/;
var password = '$$$h1Tzzzz';
password.match(pattern);
//output
["$$$h1Tzzzz"]
password = '$$$hTzzzz';
password.match(pattern);
//output
null
```

You can add your special characters to the brackets with \$ and !. '$' is escaped because it has special meaning.

Comment: __a)__ What regex flavour is this? In the ones I know, `.*`, matches anything, 0 or more times. These 0 or more anythings should be followed by the bracketed characters. __b)__ Again, in the flavours I know, your regex would match the beginning of the string/line (`^`), but only if followed by `.*[a-z]`, but only if ....., and that 6 to 26 times. Tbh, I can't make any sense of your regex. Would you be so kind to explain it?

Comment: @phresnel **a)** JavaScript regex are Perl-style with some limitations. Your assumption is right. `.*` matches anything 0 or more times. **b)** Not quite so. It matches `^` anyway. `(?=regex)` is a zero-width positive lookahead. Matches at a position where the pattern inside the lookahead can be matched. Matches only the position. It does not consume any characters or expand the match. Thus whenever it is out of the `(?=[\$!])` it's still at the beginning of the string and the string is containing all required characters. Then it checks the length `.{6, 20}$`